# Google App Engine Repository and Android Studio

Tags: git, google-app-engine, android-studio

According to https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/gcloud/ , Google App Engine creates a Git Repository on the google server which will host my project.

The repository has the URL: https://source.developers.google.com/p//
Previously, I have been able to use the gcloud command line too to commit code to this repository.

When I attempt to use Android Studio to connect to this repository (create a new project by cloning the repository, for example), I am prompted for a username and password. The google credentials I used to create the project do not work here (my google account and password, or even my google account and an "app password", since I have 2factor auth enabled).

I have run the command "gcloud auth login" successfully, but still android studio is not able to connect to the repository.

This seems like a pretty straightforward task, and I'm fairly baffled as to why I am having so much trouble. There seems to be little or no documentation on using this repository.

Should I be able to do this? and if so, what am I missing? Sorry for the frustration... thanks in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password for this repository is an oauth2 access token. If you create the repository using `gcloud init YOUR_PROJECT`, the repository will tie itself to gcloud and use the access tokens it generates.

You can also have gcloud just print out a valid access token for your active account by running `gcloud auth print-access-token`. Use this if you prefer to set up your repository using something other than `gcloud init YOUR_PROJECT`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. Is this documented somewhere that I missed?